# Придаточное образа действия/степени или времени?

Tags: синтаксис, придаточное-предложение

В игре он давал сопернику фору, но с каждым разом фора становилась все меньше, **пока они не сравнялись в умении.**

Answer (score 4):

(1) В игре он давал сопернику фору, (2) но с каждым разом фора становилась все меньше, (3) пока они не сравнялись в умении.

Придаточное времени (3) относится к главному предложению (2).

Сочинительная связь между предложением (1) и СПП (1 и 2), союз НО.

Comment: oouuuhh Vera, я Вас люблю! Вы такая умная!!! Если бы я не была бедной студенткой, я купила бы Вам билет к моему дому и задавала бы Вам всегда вопросы! ... но Вы наверноe убежали бы от меня на следующий день : ) jejejeje Спасибо еще раз!!!

Comment: А я люблю отвечать на вопросы. Как раз два года назад я случайно зашла на этот форум (надо будет отметить юбилей), ответила на какой-то вопрос, записала адрес с пометкой "интересный сайт". Потом вернулась недели через две, с удивлением обнаружив, что мне присвоили звание "учитель", решила - ошибка какая-то!  Освоилась с большим трудом, но теперь привыкла к  общению, к людям, к вопросам. Спасибо за добрые слова Вам и всем остальным, кто так часто говорит мне "спасибо" (а я не всегда могу им ответить),  от этого теплее становится на душе.

Comment: ... приятно читать то, что Вы написали!!! Люди, готовые просто так помогать, просто потому что у них сердце доброе, очень большая редкость на сегодня! Посылаю Вам крепкое обьятие!!! : )

Answer (score 2):

Это придаточное времени. *Давал фору* (до каких пор? ) *пока*...